# How to get a certain word from a filename in PHP?

Tags: php, filenames

Is it possible to get the word "Test", "Prototype" and "Super" in the following filenames:

```
MyCSV - Test.csv
MyCSV - Prototype.csv
MyCSV - Super.csv
```

Comment: It is - find the last dot. Then the last space before dot. Then cut everything between those.

Comment: if your starting prefix string is fix then you can also try string replace function and first replace "MyCSV - " and then replace ".csv" from your file name to archive your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
echo explode('.',explode('- ',$filename)[1])[0];
```

Output:-https://eval.in/979069

***Explanation:-***

first, explode with `-`(hyphen and space) and get the last value using `[1]` (because you are getting array after explode so you can use the index to get particular value and it will give you value like `Test.csv`,`Prototype.csv`,`Super.csv`....so on).

again explode with `.` and use the first value using `[0]` as a final result.(because you are getting array after explode so you can use the index to get particular value and it will give you value like `Test`,`Prototype`,`Super`....so on).

***Check this split code for better understanding:-*** https://eval.in/979077

Answer (score 1):

use pathinfo() to strip out the extension, then use preg_split to split the words by spaces and hypens, then use array_unique to remove any duplicates, eg

```
$words=array_unique(preg_split("/[\\s\\-]+/u",pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_FILENAME)));
```

now if you only want the last word of the filename,

```
$str=$words[count($words)-1];
```

or if you want all words except the first,

```
unset($words[0]);
$str=implode(" ",$words);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the `substr()` function.

It's much easier to use but it needs consistency on the filenames so it will be easy to slice the filenames.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes I have tried and run it. +1 for easier way.

Comment: Glad to help you :):)